# What are R for Windows' "Current Version" and "Install Path" registry entries used for?

Tags: windows, r, registry

Here are the two registry entries I'm asking about.**

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\R-core\R\Current Version
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\R-core\R\version\InstallPath
```

When R is launched from the command line (or from **emacs**, or **statconnDCOM** for that matter) it uses whatever version appears first in Windows' `Path` environment variable. By contrast, double clicking on a `*.Rdata` file uses the version pointed to by the relevant file association entry in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.

But when or by what are the two `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` entries used?

**EDIT:** Brian Diggs points to a bundle of Windows `*.bat` files that do use (and modify) these registry entries, but I'm still interested in whether anything closer to 'core' R uses these. (I'm hoping the answer is 'no'.)

---

** As described in the [R for Windows FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Does-R-use-the-Registry_003f), these entries may be set either during installation (by clicking 'Save version number in registry') or later from the command line (by typing `RSetReg.exe` from within `$RHOME\bin`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Major edit:**

It looks like those registry entries are primarily there for use by external applications.

Here's why I think that.

1. grep'ing `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` in the R sources turns up four hits in just three files. The files -- `"extra.c"`, `"RSetReg.c"`, and `"rhome.c"` -- are all located in `R-2.15.0/src/gnuwin/` or its subdirectories.
2. The relevant occurrence appears to be that in `R-2.15.0/src/gnuwin/rhome.c`, where it is used by the C function `get_R_HOME`. That function is designed to

   > /* get R_HOME from environment or registry: used in embedded apps */

   and it searches in the registry only if `R_HOME` if it has not yet been found in the "C environment space" or the "Windows API environment space".
3. `get_R_HOME`, in turn, only appears in two other files, `"R-2.15.0/src/gnuwin/embeddedR.c"`, and `"R-2.15.0/src/gnuwin/front-ends/rtest.c"`. (According to its resident `readme` file, the role of `"R-2.15.0/src/gnuwin/front-ends/"` is to make it possible to "Link[...] the R DLL into other applications".)
4. R's *NIX origins and emphasis on portability make it seem unlikely that anything close to R's core functionality would depend on registry entries. (This item's obviously way more speculative.)

Unless I hear otherwise, that's enough to convince me that the registry entries' only purpose is to provide pointers for external applications, particularly those that use an embedded instance of R.

Comment: That sounds right. On Windows, if I ever have to run an R script from a different application, I would use these registry entries to find where R has been installed.

Answer (score 3):

One set of programs which use these are the [R batchfiles](https://code.google.com/p/batchfiles/) which states

> These programs set the version of R (and version of R Tools and miktex) by (1) examining environment variables (R_HOME, R_MIKTEX, R_TOOLS) or (2) if not set they look in the registry.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks! It looks like ~ half of that bundle is designed to provide an alternative version-dispatch system for R on Windows. I'm *still* curious whether anything closer to the 'core' of R uses those registry entries.  Given R's platform independence and `*NIX` origins, I'm *leaning* towards "no".